# Add button to certain cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created a Datagridview.
Now whenever the cell contains an empty value, It will add the plus button to the cell. Something like this:

```
if ((string)((Hashtable)ht[i])["value"] == "")
  {
     // Create a Save button column
     DataGridViewImageButtonSaveColumn columnSave = new DataGridViewImageButtonSaveColumn();

     // Set column values

     //Add the columns to the grid6
     if (!dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("SaveButton"))
        {
           dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(5, columnSave);
        }
  }
  else
  {
     //hide save button.
  }
```

But now my problem is that it display the plus button at all cell for that column even though that particular cell have value. How can I hide the button for the cell that have value?

Comment: Are you saying that you want an extra column but you only want buttons displayed in that column for the rows where a cell in another column is empty?  Or are you saying that you actually want to put a button in a cell in an existing column?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yeah, i've created a column for the button to be display.Now I want like whenever the datagrid add new rows,it check that cell. if empty then add the button,if have value, hide the button. Only for that cell.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want buttons in some rows then I would tend not to use a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`.  I would use a read-only `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, so that it displays empty cells by default.  For those rows where you want a button, you would then create a `DataGridViewButtonCell` and use the indexer of the grid itself to place that cell at a specific column and row index.

Comment: Yep,that is what i have created. but when the particular cell have the button. The next row generated also will automatically add the button

Comment: There is no "automatically" if you've done what I suggested.  The only time a cell will contain a button is when you put one there so if you're not seeing what you intended then you're doing it wrong.  As I have no idea what you're doing, I can't know what's wrong with it.